# figure* environment in two column article does not work

Tags: floats, captions, two-column

I've have used `figure*` environment throughout all the article but suddenly stops working and i don't no way, it only shows some quotation marks.

Here a sample code, sorry for the not so clear question but it is urgent.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Specify a different language here - english by default

\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text. To be removed otherwise

\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}

\usepackage{gensymb} % per fare il cerchiolino de gradi 

\usepackage{float} % per mettere le figure dove voglio

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %elimina il rientro quando vai a capo


\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicols

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]

 \includegraphics[angle=90,scale=0.2]{FULL_STRUCTURE/DOMAIN_PATTERN/ciao}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where did you get `SelfArx.cls` from?

Comment: i'm using a template of a scientific article and that files comes with it

Comment: unless you show us a link to the class it is impossible to say anything as there is no figure environment pre-defined its definition is always in the class. Note that two column floats do not have `h` option so `[!h]`  specifies that the float is not allowed at top of the page or on a float page so it will not be allowed anywhere so will go to the end of the document (or `\clearpage`)

Comment: It is also possible that the image is too big, which is why you should always include the [p] option.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put any options to the `figure*` environment, just plain `\begin{figure*}`. If you do provide an option then the figure will end up on the last page of the document.

For example:

```
% twocolfigprob.tex SE 548808
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=90, height=0.99\textheight,width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

I was unable to process your MWE. I don't know the class that you are using, nor the particular graphic you are using so I have used the `article` class and one of the "standard" images from the `mwe` package.

Comment: yes i'm doing like that, but it does not work, maybe should I mention that I'm using \includegraphics[angle=90] , this angle option seems to cause the problem, but i don't know why

Comment: @Andrea I have extended my answer for the general case. Perhaps the problem is with the `SelfArx` class (whatever that is).